# JMeter response throwing "File Name is Invalid / Already Exists" on uploading Blazemeter Recording File

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I'm using Apache Jmeter version 5.3. And i am **using Blazemeter** for recording the "File Upload" request and for which Jmeter is throwing *"File Name is Invalid / Already Exists".* But the file i am trying to achieve upload has a new name which doesn't previously exist. Application is running on Azure server.

PS: I tried the file upload manually with the same filename and the upload was successful (Tried this after jmeter failed to achieve it)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot suggest anything without seeing your test plan (or at least request) and knowing what is the contract for the file upload endpoint

So I can provide only a generic piece of advice: just compare the network request(s) associated with the file upload coming from the real browser and JMeter, identify the differences and amend your JMeter configuration so it would send the same request as the real browser does (apart from the dynamic file name and other dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)). The comparison can be performed using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

You can also try using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for recording your file upload event, just **make sure to have the file you're uploading in JMeter's bin folder**, this way JMeter will be able to generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.